# name Path is not defined pyhton

Tags: python

I got this error in jupyter notebook python:

```
name 'path' is not defined
```

for my long code but I think it is not code related. I also install path from pathlib does not work

Grabing list of images directories

```
images = glob.glob('.//views//**.png')
print ('There are {} images available'.format(len(images)))
print ('First image has {} number of pixels'.format(len(cv.imread(path, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,0].flatten())))      
print ('First image shape is {} '.format(cv.imread(path, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV).shape))
```

Can you help?

Try to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet path indicates, Path of the image. By analyzing your approch I guess you are trying to pass ecah list elemnt as a path input.

### Code correction

```
images = glob.glob('.//views//**.png')
print ('There are {} images available'.format(len(images)))

for path in images:

    print ('First image has {} number of pixels'.format(len(cv.imread(path, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,0].flatten())))      
    print ('First image shape is {} '.format(cv.imread(path, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV).shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

`path` hasn't been instantiated/has no value/isn't defined.
Prior to the print statement where `path` is used, you should give `path` a value.

Comment: I checked the web and it seems that this is general error. Yep I see that path is not defined before